# How to use Primefaces autocomplete with a POJO List and a POJO's property as selection value

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, primefaces

In our current project we want to replace a `<h:selectOneMenu>` with Primefaces's `<p:autocomplete>`. The select items are a list of Pojos (JPA Entities). The difference to the given examples in primefaces [showcases](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf) is, that we want the primary key property (id) of the entity as selection value, so it can be easily passed as view param:

```xml
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="playerId" value="#{playerPreRenderViewListener.searchCriteria.playerId}" />
    <f:viewParam name="year" value="#{playerPreRenderViewListener.searchCriteria.year}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{playerPreRenderViewListener.searchCriteria.year}"/>
    <p:autoComplete var="player" itemLabel="#{player.name}" itemValue="#{player.id}"
        completeMethod="#{playerBean.completePlayer}" forceSelection="true"
        converter="#{playerConverter}" 
        value="#{playerPreRenderViewListener.searchCriteria.playerId}">
    </p:autoComplete>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="showTeam?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true" />
</h:form>
```

Unfortunately the example above will lead to a PropertyNotFoundException:

> itemLabel="#{player.name}": Property 'name' not found on type java.lang.Long'

The problem is that the `var` attribute is of Type `Long` and not `Player`. When using a simple `<h:selectMenu>` it works in conjunction with `<f:selectItems>`:

```xml
<f:selectItems var="player" value="#{playerBean.listPlayers}" itemLabel="#{player.name}" itemValue="#{player.id}" />
```

Does anybody know how to handle this issue?

Comment: Can you provide code snippet of your player converter, please? I have ran into the same issue and want to use a converter for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a backing bean method that returns the player belonging to the currently active `playerId` and set this `currentPlayer` as value attribute of your backing bean:

```
public Player getCurrentPlayer() {
  // find player by playerId and return
}
```

And in the view:

```
<p:autoComplete var="player" itemLabel="#{player.name}" itemValue="#{player}"
        completeMethod="#{playerBean.completePlayer}" forceSelection="true"
        converter="#{playerConverter}" 
        value="#{playerPreRenderViewListener.currentPlayer}">
```

Comment: thx, but this would mean having one getter and on setter for the view params, and another getter and setter for the autocomplete. Plus - on each preRenderView you have to lookup the player object for the id given as viewparam. isnt there a simpler way, as we had it with h:selectOneMenu?

Comment: in the example above you mean `itemValue="#{player}"` i guess (without id)?

Comment: You could set the `currentPlayer` in the setter for `playerId`. Btw: What is your PlayerPreRenderViewListener? Is it a phase listener?

Comment: thx matt. the problem is, that in the code above `searchCriteria` is just a simple transfer object. itself can not lookup a player. in our use case players are fetched from db. PS: playerPreRenderViewListener is just a request scoped backing bean for initialisation on PreRenderViewEvent, could be playerBean as well.

Comment: just not so nice, that you have to define a `playerConverter` + a lookup method for the given playerId. when you use `h:selectMenu` a converter is enough. from my point of view this could be an approvement for primefaces autocomplete.

Comment: You could submit a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) for this. You got my vote!

Comment: okay, created issue [3750](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3750)

Comment: will u please provide code snippet of playerConverter